# Is it mandatory to configure DataSource in Spring starter project?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, web

I want to create a basic Spring started application and make a get request. I have added Spring JPA, Spring Web dependencies and started running in port 8080, but my application to start. It says
" Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.
Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class ".

I have not added any database dependency cause I don't require it, Is that mandatory to have database dependency in my project?
Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.3.1.RELEASE
 

com.example
java-sample-project
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
java-sample-project
Demo project for Spring Boot

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: You are including JPA. How are you going to use JPA without a dtabase?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you include Spring JPA, then yes, it's mandatory.

But you can easily disable the Spring autoconfigration:

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=
  org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration, \
  org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration, \
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration
```

Comment: Which is a workaround. If one doesn't need JPA (or DB access) you simply shouldn't include it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is mandatory. But if you don't want to have a real database running, then use the in-memory database H2. Just add com.h2database:h2 to the dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

You might be having the data dependency in your POM: (or build.gradle)

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

If so, please remove that.